# Passing data from a file to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a Python person and dont understand Javascript. However i am stuck at a situation where I am generating a data stream from a python script that needs to be consumed by a javascript to display a wordcloud. I am using wordcloud2.js

I need to be able to pass the data to the variable 'list' (as below) from an external file (url). I tried several things from the internet but nothing seems to work. Can someone please help me fix it.

```
<script>
var div = document.getElementById("sourrounding_div");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_cloud");
canvas.height = div.offsetHeight;
canvas.width  = div.offsetWidth;
var options = 
{
  list : [['A1', 20.0],['A2',30],['A3',40],],

  gridSize: Math.round(0.21 * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024),
  weightFactor: function (size) {
    return Math.pow(size, 1.4) * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024;
  }
}
WordCloud(document.getElementById('canvas_cloud'), options); 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand what your problem is exactly? Is it that you do not know how to request data from the server?

Comment: Are you able to get it working using static data?

Comment: yes, the above mentioned script works correctly, I just want to be able to read the list from a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX (JSON returned example):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status == 200) {
    var list = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  }
};

request.send();
```

Remember that a request is asynchronous.